# When I try to setState in useEffect it doesnt work

Tags: reactjs, google-cloud-firestore, react-hooks

After getting the documents I want and storing as objects in an array shown here

```
const appealsRef = collection(db, "appeals");
const today = new Date();
const getAppeals = async (logicalOp) => {
        const q = query(appealsRef, where("toDate", logicalOp, convertDateToTimestamp(today)))
        const querySnapshot = await getDocs(q);
        let dummyAppeals = []; 
        querySnapshot.docs.map((doc) => {
            const docData = { ...doc.data() };
            getOrgByDocID(docData.orgDocID)
                .then((res) => {
                    const appealData = {
                        ...docData,
                        orgName : res.orgName, 
                        orgAddress : res.orgAddress
                    }
                    dummyAppeals.push(appealData)
                    
                })
        });
        return dummyAppeals
    }
```

I would like to set the results in state variables `currentAppeals` and `pastAppeals` based on the `logicalOp` given in `useEffect` and then set it into another state variable array appeals using `setAppeals`;  this is because depending on what the user clicks on which is past or present I would like to set the appeals array to `currentAppeals` if present is clicked or `pastAppeals` if past is clicked.

The code involved :

```
const [ currentAppeals, setCurrentAppeals ] = useState([]);
const [ appeals, setAppeals ] = useState([]);
useEffect(() => {
        getAppeals(">=")
            .then((res) => {
                setCurrentAppeals(res);
                setAppeals(currentAppeals.map((appeal, i) => {
                    return (
                        <AppealCard
                            appealID={appeal.appealID}
                            from={appeal.fromDate}
                            to={appeal.toDate}
                            orgName={appeal.orgName}
                            orgAddress={appeal.orgAddress}
                            outcome={appeal.outcome}/>
                    )
                }));
            });
    }, []);
```

And then I will display the `appeals` in the react component here :

```
<div className='view-appealsBody'>
        {
            appeals
        }
</div>
```

But the `appeals` are not set after `setAppeals` in `useEffect()`.

Comment: `getOrgByDocID` appears to be asynchronous. You'd need to resolve all those promises using `Promise.all()`

Comment: It was and I didn't know how to resolve all promises and return it before, but now I do thanks for @Drew Reese and your help!

Comment: Can I ask how should I close this question now that it has been resolved?

Comment: You've accepted an answer which is all you need to do. Throw a few upvotes to helpful answers if you can

Comment: I see, but I dont have 15 reputation or more so unfortunately I can't upvote, but again thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Issues

1. `getAppeals` doesn't wait for the `dummyAppeals` array to become populated, it simply returns the empty array while the asynchronous code in the map callback runs.
2. React state updates are processed asynchronously, so `currentAppeals` is still the initial empty array value when the code tries to map it to JSX.
3. It's anti-pattern in React to store JSX in state. You should instead store the data and map the state to JSX when rendering. This avoid any stale enclosures over any previous state values.

## Solution

Update `getAppeals` to return the array of resolved promises containing the appeals

```
const appealsRef = collection(db, "appeals");
const today = new Date();

const getAppeals = async (logicalOp) => {
  const q = query(appealsRef, where("toDate", logicalOp, convertDateToTimestamp(today)));
  const querySnapshot = await getDocs(q);

  return Promise.all(querySnapshot.docs.map((doc) => {
    const docData = { ...doc.data() };
    return getOrgByDocID(docData.orgDocID)
      .then((res) => ({
        ...docData,
        orgName : res.orgName, 
        orgAddress : res.orgAddress
      }))
    })
  );
};
```

...

```
const [currentAppeals, setCurrentAppeals] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
  getAppeals(">=").then((res) => setCurrentAppeals(res));
}, []);

return (
  ...
  {currentAppeals.map((appeal, i) => (
    <AppealCard
      key={appeal.appealID}
      appealID={appeal.appealID}
      from={appeal.fromDate}
      to={appeal.toDate}
      orgName={appeal.orgName}
      orgAddress={appeal.orgAddress}
      outcome={appeal.outcome}/>
    ))}
  ...
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this out

```
// const [ currentAppeals, setCurrentAppeals ] = useState([]);
const [ appeals, setAppeals ] = useState([]);
useEffect(() => {
        getAppeals(">=")
            .then((res) => {
              // setCurrentAppeals(res);
                setAppeals(res.map((appeal, i) => {
                    return (
                        <AppealCard
                            appealID={appeal.appealID}
                            from={appeal.fromDate}
                            to={appeal.toDate}
                            orgName={appeal.orgName}
                            orgAddress={appeal.orgAddress}
                            outcome={appeal.outcome}/>
                    )
                }));
            });
    }, []);
```

Answer (score 0):

you must set appeals as second parameter in useEffect

```js
useEffect(() => {
        getAppeals(">=")
            .then((res) => {
                setCurrentAppeals(res);
                
            });
    }, [appeals]);
```

and better put this code to return the body of component

```js
currentAppeals.map((appeal, i) => {
                    return (
                        <AppealCard
                            appealID={appeal.appealID}
                            from={appeal.fromDate}
                            to={appeal.toDate}
                            orgName={appeal.orgName}
                            orgAddress={appeal.orgAddress}
                            outcome={appeal.outcome}/>
                    )
                });
```

Answer (score 0):

It happens because React setState is an asynchronous function. You're setting  `appeals`  using previously set state i.e `currentAppeals`. Instead of try to set it using `res` only like:

```
const [ currentAppeals, setCurrentAppeals ] = useState([]);
const [ appeals, setAppeals ] = useState([]);
useEffect(() => {
        getAppeals(">=")
            .then((res) => {
                setCurrentAppeals(res);
                setAppeals(res.map((appeal) => {
                    return (
                        <AppealCard
                            key={appeal.appealID}
                            appealID={appeal.appealID}
                            from={appeal.fromDate}
                            to={appeal.toDate}
                            orgName={appeal.orgName}
                            orgAddress={appeal.orgAddress}
                            outcome={appeal.outcome}/>
                    )
                }));
            });
    }, []);
```